# setMargin() method not worked for QVBoxLayout in Qt Python

Tags: python, pyside

I use PySide instead, therefore in my program, instead

```
from PySide.QtGui import QVBoxLayout
```

Normally it works for importing but then when I called method .setMargin() as the tutorial : https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/tutorials/expenses/expenses.html#right-side-layout, I got an error:

```
self.right = QVBoxLayout()
self.right.setMargin(10)
```

> AttributeError: 'PySide.QtGui.QVBoxLayout' object has no attribute
>   'setMargin'

I tried to find the setMargin() in the library and it appear here: https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtWidgets/QLayout.html#PySide2.QtWidgets.PySide2.QtWidgets.QLayout.setMargin. That means I can call it by importing QLayout from Pyside.QtGui but that doesn't work. The cmd say:

> NotImplementedError: 'QLayout' represents a C++ abstract class and
>   cannot be instantiated

Could you please show me how to use setMargin() by an alternative way in my case?

Comment: If you have 2 different questions then post 2 different posts

Comment: I think the problem is that you are using PySide, which is older version. Try PySide2 
as that works with PyQt5 for which your tutorial is for.

Comment: PySide2 is not compatible with python2 so you will not be able to install it if you continue using that version, I recommend installing python3

Answer (score 5):

`setMargin()` does not exist in Qt4 (PySide), it existed in initial versions of Qt5 but is currently deprecated, instead you must use the [`setContentsMargins()`](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qlayout.html#setContentsMargins-2) method:

```
self.right = QVBoxLayout()
self.right.setContentsMargins(10, 10, 10, 10)
```

Comment: *"it existed in initial versions of Qt5 but is currently deprecated"* yes. It is in [Obsolete Members for QLayout](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout-obsolete.html#setMargin) of Qt 5 and does not exist in Qt 6.